# Android LiveData Observer only receive last emitted value

Tags: android, android-livedata

So, I have ViewModel that looks like this

```
class MyViewModel<E, S> : ViewModel() {

    private val _state = MutableLiveData<S>()
    val state: LiveData<S>
        get() = _state

    abstract fun onEventReceived(event: E)

    protected fun pushState(state: S) {
        _state.value = state
    }
}
```

And as usual I have observer code in my Activity/ Fragment

```
viewModel.state.observe(this, Observer {
    // Do something here
})
```

My problem is when I try to emit values like this

```
pushState(State.A)
pushState(State.B)
pushState(State.C)
```

In my Activity/Fragment, it only received `C`.

Anyone has experience with this kind of behaviour? Please kindly share your workaround.

Comment: I execute these 3 `pushState` lines in `onCreate` method. But somehow, only the last emitted value got received by the observer

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55212795/9381524

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52732285