Livedata setvalue is ignored when called multiple times
In the following code only functionC is invoked. getValues method is called from Main thread from a fragment, but function A and FunctionB are skipped
class MyViewModel() {
fun getValues(){
_livedata.value = SomeFuctionA()
_livedata.value = SomeFuctionB()
_livedata.value = SomeFuctionC()
}
}

However if I modify the method to launch explicitly from main thread, all functions are called
class MyViewModel() {
fun getValues(){
viewmodelScope.launch(Dispathers.Main){
_livedata.value = SomeFuctionA()
_livedata.value = SomeFuctionB()
_livedata.value = SomeFuctionC()
}
}
}

This is not making sense because getValues is invoked from MainThread in both cases, however all functions are observed only in second case. How to ideally make sure livedata is observed for all three functions ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50582682/multiple-calls-to-set-livedata-is-not-observed

Calling methods in onCreate causes the above issue as livedata is only observed after onStart

The intent with LiveData is that you only care about the most recent value. It’s not an event system. If you care about intermediate values it’s not the right tool for your job.

This question is similar to: Multiple calls to set LiveData is not observed. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Let’s discuss about your first code snippet in which three functions values are getting saved in _livedata, here whats happening is that data of functionA is getting overridden by functionB and then by functionC. And it’s happening so fast that it’s looking to you that functionA and functionB is getting skipped, because functionC is overriding the data very fast.
Now, discussing about your second code snippet, here you have used the coroutine and because of that coroutine are getting created and delaying the result of function, functionB and functionC. Because of that you are able to get the result, but it’s still wrong as it will override the data at the end.  Your code is also not maintaining the right coding standard in this scenario.  
So, your both code snippets are wrong(because -> setting the value "_livedata.value=" will replace old data with new, its a feature of liveData).
Solution
You have multiple ways to solve this problem.  

Use a list to emit all the results together. 
You can modify your liveData to emit a list of results(from all functions) rather than just a single result (from only one function).

In this way observer will receive a list containing all the data of functionA, functionB, functionC.
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
private val _livedata = MutableLiveData<List<ResultType>>() // Assume ResultType is the type returned by your functions
val livedata: LiveData<List<ResultType>> = _livedata

fun getValues() {
    // Collect all the results
    val results = listOf(
        SomeFunctionA(),
        SomeFunctionB(),
        SomeFunctionC()
    )

    // Emit the entire list
    _livedata.value = results
}

}
Observation in fragment
viewModel.livedata.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { results ->
results.forEach { result ->
    // Process each result individually
}

})

Using MediatorLiveData.

if you have used this before you know that when data is coming from
multiple sources then mediatorLiveData is best to use as it add all
the data from different sources and provide you the result.
  If you have not tried mediatorLiveData below is the official page of
it.

mediatorLiveData
first create different liveData for each functions, which will allow you to handle the liveData separately.
Working method:
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
private val _liveDataA = MutableLiveData<ResultType>()
private val _liveDataB = MutableLiveData<ResultType>()
private val _liveDataC = MutableLiveData<ResultType>()

// Use MediatorLiveData to combine all LiveData results
val combinedLiveData = MediatorLiveData<List<ResultType>>().apply {
    val resultList = mutableListOf<ResultType>()

    // Add sources for each LiveData
    addSource(_liveDataA) { resultA ->
        resultList.add(resultA)
        value = resultList.toList()  // Update the MediatorLiveData with the combined result
    }

    addSource(_liveDataB) { resultB ->
        resultList.add(resultB)
        value = resultList.toList()
    }

    addSource(_liveDataC) { resultC ->
        resultList.add(resultC)
        value = resultList.toList()
    }
}

// Function to get values and update individual LiveData objects
fun getValues() {
    _liveDataA.value = SomeFunctionA()
    _liveDataB.value = SomeFunctionB()
    _liveDataC.value = SomeFunctionC()
}

}
MediatorLiveData observes all the three different liveData source(_liveDataA, _liveDataB, _liveDataC)  and each time any function (A, B,C ) updates its respective liveData, mediatorLiveData will combines the result into a list and update it to the observer.

What about using coroutine flows? I tried them but one of issues that I faced was that last value is re-emitted when app goes to background and comes back.

Thats a good idea of using Flow. If you are facing the issue about the last value re-emitted. I would recommend you to use sharedFlow with replay = 0, which ensures no old values are re-emitted when the collector(UI) re-subscribe, such as when the app resumes.
private val _sharedFlow = MutableSharedFlow(replay = 0)
val sharedFlow: SharedFlow = _sharedFlow
alternatiely, If you can use a simple flow, which will only emit new values as they are collected without holding onto previous emissions.

You can call it on any thread with all of them executing just like below code
_livedata.value = SomeFuctionA()
joinAll()
_livedata.value = SomeFuctionB()
joinAll()
_livedata.value = SomeFuctionC()

You can only use joinAll() in a coroutine or a suspend function. Keep that in mind.
Also a little extra, if you want some delay when being executed add below code
delay(10.seconds)

